# split text in textformfield with a character in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

perhaps someone has encountered such a problem, I need to configure textformfield so that the text is entered in the form in the format **/** so that the user does not have to type / himself, it seems like you need to use inputformatter, but I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

```
    maskformatter.dart

class MaskedTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final String? mask;
  final String? separator;

  MaskedTextInputFormatter({
    @required this.mask,
    @required this.separator,
  }) {
    assert(mask != null);
    assert(separator != null);
  }

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.isNotEmpty) {
      if (newValue.text.length > oldValue.text.length) {
        if (newValue.text.length > mask!.length) return oldValue;
        if (newValue.text.length < mask!.length &&
            mask![newValue.text.length - 1] == separator) {
          return TextEditingValue(
            text:
                '${oldValue.text}$separator${newValue.text.substring(newValue.text.length - 1)}',
            selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
              offset: newValue.selection.end + 1,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
    return newValue;
  }
```

in textfield use :-

```
inputFormatter: [
                   MaskedTextInputFormatter(
                   mask: '****-****-****-****',
                   separator: '-',
                  ),
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for mask text. Try this package [mask_text](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter)

```dart
var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(
  mask: '+# (###) ###-##-##', 
  filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[0-9]') },
  type: MaskAutoCompletionType.lazy
);
```

And assign it to the textfield

```dart
TextField(inputFormatters: [maskFormatter])
```